# Exclude indices from elasticsearch snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to exclude a few indices from elastic snapshot , in the documentation for snapshots , they mention you can include what indices you need , but I need it other way around , because I need to snapshot all indices except a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snapshot syntax supports [multi-index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) syntax,
Hence you can exclude them with `-` before indice name.

Comment: If you just use exclusions does it snapshot everything else?

Comment: Looks like we cannot exclude aliases :(

Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 5):

I found that before excluding anything, you need to include everything. Here's the syntax that works for me to e.g. include all but the filebeat and metricbeat indices:

```
*,-filebeat-*,-metricbeat-*
```

(I post an answer as I cannot comment...)